# Launching an application via Finder and enabling env variables for logging

Tags: macos, finder, console, environment-variables

I want to launch an application via Finder in a current Mac OS X. I want to enable some logging modules, which can be set by export NAME=etc on the console, but I want to include them in the Finder-launch.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know why this got down-voted, it's a perfectly reasonable question. What kind of application are you trying to launch? Is it a GUI app, or command line app?

Comment: Hi, it's about a GUI app. I did not know that this question was down-voted. Where do you see this?

Comment: It was at -1, now back to 0. As far as I know you can't do what your asking for a GUI app launched by the finder. Any environment variables set would be used in the terminal (shell) session only. However have a look at `man open`. `open` has an `--args` parameter that might be of use. I haven't tried this though.